# Display data with NSURL

Tags: ios, swift

I downloaded some data (pfg file, or html document) and want to display it in `UIWebView`. if I have a path, what should i write to show data in the path?

```
let documentsDirectoryURL =  NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
```

Comment: let try this `let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("FileName", withExtension:"html") `. let me know if it works.

Comment: @JaleelNazir i dont know name of the file, i tried to download it with this                  let s = "http://www.qdtricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hd-wallpapers-1080p-for-mobile.png"
        let url = NSURL(string:s)!
        let req = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
        let task = self.session.downloadTaskWithRequest(req)
        self.task = task
        task.resume()

Comment: come to [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78976/swift-webview)

Comment: i couldnt chat there, no enough reputation , i already tried this let url = NSURL (string: "http://www.qdtricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/hd-wallpapers-1080p-for-mobile.png%22");
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
self.myWebView.loadRequest(requestObj); but i have to show data which was already downloaded

Comment: you should probably load the content from the Document Directory(its where you downloaded) and display in UIWebView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS, you can't write into a file in your app's bundle -- the entire bundle is read-only. Use a path into the Documents folder instead.

I hope its help's you...

```
    let myURLString = "http://google.com"
    var myHTMLString : NSString!

    if let myURL = NSURL(string: myURLString) {
        var error: NSError?
        myHTMLString = NSString(contentsOfURL: myURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

        if let error = error {
            println("Error : \(error)")
        } else {
            //                println("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
        }
    } else {
        println("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")

    }


    let file = "file.html"

    if let dirs : [String] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
        let dir = dirs[0] //documents directory
        let path = dir.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);
        let text = myHTMLString

        //writing
        text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

        //reading
        let text2 = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)

    //  var text2 : NSString = NSString.stringWithContentsOfURL(NSURL(string: "http://google.com"), encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) as NSString

    var htmlString:String! = text2
    myWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```

But where javascript files are not work

**OR**

You may add files into Bundle and load it into your webview.

```
let paths =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("File", withExtension:"html", subdirectory: "Pages")
// let paths =  NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("File", withExtension:"html")

println("HTML : \(paths)")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL:paths!);
myWebView.loadRequest(request)
```